# Unit test project failing due to reference issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a unit test to test one of my model classes and I get the follow error when I try building unit test target:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMyClass", referenced from: 
objc-class-ref-to-NSMyClass in LogicTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I have setup my unit tests as Apple recommends i.e. separate targets.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the source under test (in addition to the test cases) in the test case target?

Comment: So everytime I want to run unit tests I have to drag the .h and .m files into the compiles sources folder?

Comment: @TheLearner: no, just the first time you want to build the target. Unlike JUnit you can't just take a single test case file and "Run as OCUnit test case" - something which bugs me and which I'm talking about at a conference soon...

Comment: so I have dragged my 'model' files into the compile sources folder - should I just leave them there and whenever I add another model drag it aswell?

Comment: @TheLearner: whenever you add new code that needs to be tested, yes.